# Search catalog and list products from a single store

Tags: category, multistore, model, catalogsearch

I am trying to filter the products of a category, I talk about the catalog search, I'm working in a multi-store and I need to filter only the products in the catalog of a store. I filter this in the model.

Comment: You want to filter product according to store view??

Comment: exactly friend, look for the products of the categories that belong to a store, in a multi-store environment

Answer (score 0):

```
$_rootcatID = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();

$_testproductCollection = 
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
 ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
 ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $_rootcatID))
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$_testproductCollection->load();

foreach($_testproductCollection as $_testproduct){ 
echo $this->htmlEscape($_testproduct->getName())."<br/>"; 
};
```

(OR)

```
$storeId = 1; 
$rootId = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
          ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
          ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like'=> "1/$rootId/%"));
```